# Prove that if $\kappa (t) =0$ for all $t$, then $\textbf{r}(t)$ is a straight line.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\textbf{r}(t)$ be a regular parametrized curve and $\kappa (t)$ be its curvature. Prove that if $\kappa (t) =0$ for all $t$, then $\textbf{r}(t)$ is a straight line.

I began by expanding the $\kappa (t)$ but it seemed that it is wrong. Any hints or solution please?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the definition of curvature (i.e. $\kappa (t)$) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume WLOG that ${\bf r}$ has unit speed (why can you say this?). If $\kappa(t) = \|{\bf r}''(t)\| = 0$, then ${\bf r}''(t) = 0$. Meaning that ${\bf r}(t) = {\bf p} + t{\bf v}$. Done.